# Cannot write to text file python 2.7 invalid syntax?

Tags: python, printing, gps, output

My code works perfectly, but I want it to write the values to a text file. When I try to do it, I get 'invalid syntax'. When I use a python shell, it works. So I don't understand why it isn't working in my script.

I bet it's something silly, but why wont it output the data to a text file??

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#standard module, needed as we deal with command line args
import sys

from fractions import Fraction
import pyexiv2


#checking whether we got enough args, if not, tell how to use, and exits
#if len(sys.argv) != 2 :
#    print "incorrect argument, usage: " + sys.argv[0] + ' <filename>'
#    sys.exit(1)

#so the argument seems to be ok, we use it as an imagefile 
imagefilename = sys.argv[1]



#trying to catch the exceptions in case of problem with the file reading
try:
    metadata = pyexiv2.metadata.ImageMetadata(imagefilename)
    metadata.read();

#trying to catch the exceptions in case of problem with the GPS data reading
    try:
        latitude = metadata.__getitem__("Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLatitude")
        latitudeRef = metadata.__getitem__("Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLatitudeRef")
        longitude = metadata.__getitem__("Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLongitude")
        longitudeRef = metadata.__getitem__("Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLongitudeRef")

        # get the value of the tag, and make it float number
        alt = float(metadata.__getitem__("Exif.GPSInfo.GPSAltitude").value)


        # get human readable values
        latitude = str(latitude).split("=")[1][1:-1].split(" ");
        latitude = map(lambda f: str(float(Fraction(f))), latitude)
        latitude = latitude[0] + u"\u00b0" + latitude[1] + "'" + latitude[2] + '"' + " " + str(latitudeRef).split("=")[1][1:-1]

        longitude = str(longitude).split("=")[1][1:-1].split(" ");
        longitude = map(lambda f: str(float(Fraction(f))), longitude)
        longitude = longitude[0] + u"\u00b0" + longitude[1] + "'" + longitude[2] + '"' + " " + str(longitudeRef).split("=")[1][1:-1]

        ## Printing out, might need to be modified if other format needed
        ## i just simple put tabs here to make nice columns
    print " \n A text file has been created with the following information \n"
    print "GPS EXIF data for " + imagefilename    
        print "Latitude:\t" + latitude 
        print "Longitude:\t" + longitude
        print "Altitude:\t" + str(alt) + " m"
    except Exception, e:  # complain if the GPS reading went wrong, and print the exception
        print "Missing GPS info for " + imagefilename
        print e

# Create a new file or **overwrite an existing file**
text_file = open('textfile.txt', 'w')
text_file.write("Latitude" + latitude)
# Close the output file
text_file.close()


except Exception, e:   # complain if the GPS reading went wrong, and print the exception
    print "Error processing image " + imagefilename
    print e;
```

The error I see says:

```
text_file = open('textfile.txt','w')
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please do include the *actual error* you see. We now have to guess as to what might be wrong.

Comment: And it appears you are mixing tabs and spaces. Run `python -tt` on your script to work out where your indentation has gone wonkey.

Comment: Look at the *preceding* line and make sure you have the right number of closing brackets, braces and parenthesis for the number of opening brackets, braces and parenthesis.

Comment: Also, your `text_file` lines are not indented far enough either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File open is within the first try block. It is outside the second try except block. Move it outside the first try except block or increase the indent to include them within the first try block. It should work fine there.

Also move(increase the indent) the two print statements within the try as well.

This will work for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#standard module, needed as we deal with command line args
import sys

from fractions import Fraction
import pyexiv2


#checking whether we got enough args, if not, tell how to use, and exits
#if len(sys.argv) != 2 :
#    print "incorrect argument, usage: " + sys.argv[0] + ' <filename>'
#    sys.exit(1)

#so the argument seems to be ok, we use it as an imagefile 
imagefilename = sys.argv[1]



#trying to catch the exceptions in case of problem with the file reading
try:
    metadata = pyexiv2.metadata.ImageMetadata(imagefilename)
    metadata.read();

#trying to catch the exceptions in case of problem with the GPS data reading
    try:
        latitude = metadata.__getitem__("Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLatitude")
        latitudeRef = metadata.__getitem__("Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLatitudeRef")
        longitude = metadata.__getitem__("Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLongitude")
        longitudeRef = metadata.__getitem__("Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLongitudeRef")

        # get the value of the tag, and make it float number
        alt = float(metadata.__getitem__("Exif.GPSInfo.GPSAltitude").value)


        # get human readable values
        latitude = str(latitude).split("=")[1][1:-1].split(" ");
        latitude = map(lambda f: str(float(Fraction(f))), latitude)
        latitude = latitude[0] + u"\u00b0" + latitude[1] + "'" + latitude[2] + '"' + " " + str(latitudeRef).split("=")[1][1:-1]

        longitude = str(longitude).split("=")[1][1:-1].split(" ");
        longitude = map(lambda f: str(float(Fraction(f))), longitude)
        longitude = longitude[0] + u"\u00b0" + longitude[1] + "'" + longitude[2] + '"' + " " + str(longitudeRef).split("=")[1][1:-1]

        ## Printing out, might need to be modified if other format needed
        ## i just simple put tabs here to make nice columns
        print " \n A text file has been created with the following information \n"
        print "GPS EXIF data for " + imagefilename    
        print "Latitude:\t" + latitude 
        print "Longitude:\t" + longitude
        print "Altitude:\t" + str(alt) + " m"
    except Exception, e:  # complain if the GPS reading went wrong, and print the exception
        print "Missing GPS info for " + imagefilename
        print e

    # Create a new file or **overwrite an existing file**
    text_file = open('textfile.txt', 'w')
    text_file.write("Latitude" + latitude)
    # Close the output file
    text_file.close()


except Exception, e:   # complain if the GPS reading went wrong, and print the exception
    print "Error processing image " + imagefilename
    print e;
```

Comment: thanks, just got it working now. You were right. Thank you to you and everyone who helped.

Answer (score 1):

Can be you are tabulating wrong?... The lines:

```
print " \n A text file has been created with the following information \n"
print "GPS EXIF data for " + imagefilename
```

appears to be wrong tabulated

EDIT: The code you posted -the one of the trace- is wrong tabulated, too.

Comment: might be a problem with the visualisation on SO as the code used tabs and spaces